# What is the difference between php-cli and php-fpm, why 2 php variants and why choose one or the other?

Tags: docker, php, images

Looking at https://hub.docker.com/_/php I can see reference to `php-cli` and `php-fpm`.

Now, I am aware of the concepts of PHP FPM - Fast CGI Process Manager. I'm also aware the PHP can be run in the command line and for php composer and Symfony console.

Does the Docker `php-fpm` not have PHP CLI tools like `php-fpm`. Or is `php-fpm` a superset of `php-cli` ?

Why would one choose one or the other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are different tools for different purposes:

- **php-cli** is the standalone tool for running a PHP scripts in the same way you would run it from the command line: `php somescript.php`.  It seems you can also use it to base other images from.

  > This variant contains the PHP CLI tool with default mods. If you need a web server, this is probably not the image you are looking for. It is designed to be used both as a throw away container (mount your source code and start the container to start your app), as well as a base from which to build other images.
- **php-fpm** is the FastCGI server implementation of PHP which you would use with a FastCGI compliant web server such as Apache or Nginx.

  > This variant contains PHP-FPM, which is a FastCGI implementation for PHP. See the [PHP-FPM](https://php-fpm.org/) website for more information about PHP-FPM.

You also have two other variants:

- **php-apache** which is just Apache configured with `mod_php`
- **php-alpine** is the smallest possible Docker image based upon Alpine Linux, albeit with some compatibility issues.

You can [see all of the Dockerfiles](https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.3) on GitHub and whilst it doesn't appear that `php-fpm` is based upon `php-cli` practically they are likely to be very similar and `php-fpm` is probably a superset of `php-cli`.

Comment: From this, my understanding would be php-fpm container would be used with a web server (itself in another container). This would occur both in development and production environments. Additionally, for development environments only, an additional separate php-cli container to run php composer in and symfony console in.